# Attribute is not appearing on layered navigation in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I am trying to display product attribute on layered navigation but it's not appearing.

I have already selected the **Use in Layered Navigation** -> yes,but the attribute is not appearing on layered navigation.

Comment: did this attribute have products?

Comment: yes , i have added 5 products.

Comment: then re-index and clear cache will do the trick

Comment: already did everything still not working.

Comment: What is the input type of your attribute? Only those with the catalog input type of Dropdown, Multiple Select or Price can be used as filterable attributes.

Comment: Its Dropdown, I added product attribute then added it in attribute set and later added it in sales->products but its not getting displayed. with settings as Filter with results

Comment: Same issue for the product attribute created using code, but if we create an attribute from admin it working fine. Do you fixed the issue & do you have any solution on this?

Answer (score 7):

Lets say you have an attribute called manufacturer. Then you have 5 products with the same value for manufacturer (ex. Brand X) the the manufacturer attribute will not show on the Layered navigation since all the products have the same manufacturer value.

Unless you have 1 product with Brand x and the other 4 have Brand y then the manufacturer attribute will now show up on the Layered Navigation.

Answer (score 1):

May be below are the reasons this attribute does not show up at layernagation:

Assume that you have flushed the cache and re-indexed.

- *May be the current collection doesn't have the item having this
  attribute value*.
- *May be, you did not assign the attribute to the attribute set*

  If the  you have this  type reason  then  ***you need assigned the attribute to to attributes Sets and add this attribute to some products***

Comment: Hi Amit , Thanks for your answer but attribute is already assign to specific attribute set.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the attribute settings, you also need to check each category. I.E. **the category needs to be anchored**.

While editing the category, go to the `Display Settings` tab and check that `Anchor` is set to yes.

Comment: What is the meaning of that? It is only an option if i want to show 0 filters in the catalog view page o all filters with no option to select which one?

Comment: @GianniDiFalco the anchor option is required to enable the layered navigation. https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/navigation-layered-anchor-categories.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your attribute has set to Filterable with results on Use in Layered Navigation
[image]
Also make sure your attribute type is  Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price.

Comment: I have enabled both conditions but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but when I verified from demo data, all attributes are using the **multiselect** type. To give a try I changed to attribute type multiselect it works and started displaying in the Layered Navigation.

[image]

Result

[image]